# SonarLint with C++ monorepo in VS Code - variable substitution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sonarlint

I want to use the *SonarLint* plug-in for *VS Code* in a monorepo. In the `settings.json` file I need to set the path of the `compile_commands.json` file via the `sonarlint.pathToCompileCommands` option.

The thing is that this path changes depending on which component I am currently building. The path is being configured through two *cmake* settings:

```
"cmake.sourceDirectory": "/path/to/project/being/built",
"cmake.buildDirectory": "${sourceDirectory}/build-${buildType}",
```

According to *VS Code*’s [variables reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) I would expect be able to set the `compile_commands.json` path either via `config:` or `command:` variables. The *cmake* extension seems to support [commands](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#command-substitution) as well.

```
// config variable
"sonarlint.pathToCompileCommands": "${config:cmake.buildDirectory}/compile_commands.json",

// command variable
"sonarlint.pathToCompileCommands": "${command:cmake.buildDirectory}/compile_commands.json"
```

But none of them work. What am I doing wrong? Are there maybe other ways to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: shouldn't it be `${config:cmake.buildDirectory}` and `${command:cmake.buildDirectory}` (one colon instead of two)?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. But unfortunately it doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is a known limitation. See the official variable reference FAQ entry: [Is variable substitution supported in User and Workspace settings?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_is-variable-substitution-supported-in-user-and-workspace-settings), which says:

> The predefined variables are supported in a select number of setting keys in settings.json files such as the terminal `cwd`, `env`, `shell` and `shellArgs` values. [...] Refer to the comments in the Settings editor (`Ctrl+,`) to learn about setting specific variables.